# How to select a single field for documents in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

I tried get(selected values) query in mongodb.that query in working fine in mongodb shell .but I tried to run node js it not working it showing all data.how to fix it.

query

```
db.collection('olc_prod_db_category').find({name: { $nin:['DISCONTINUE', 'LIQUOR MINI']}},{ "_id": 0}).toArray()
```

Expected ouput:

```
{ "id" : 3, "name" : "IRISH WHISKEY", "hasSubCategory" : "false", "parentId" : "30" }
```

but I got this output:

```
{
    "_id": "5b4efd6fd53be829188070ca",
    "id": 3,
    "name": "IRISH WHISKEY",
    "hasSubCategory": "false",
    "parentId": "30"
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the double quotes around _id as I think it should be a property. Not sure if this makes a big difference in object notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.project` cursor method

```
db.collection('olc_prod_db_category').find(
  { name: { $nin:['DISCONTINUE', 'LIQUOR MINI']}}
).project({ _id: 0 }).toArray()
```